# Using chunk theme from wordpress.com on my own host

Tags: themes, migration

I am new to wordpress so please excuse this question if it is obvious, but I was not able to find a good answer here or via the more general internet.

I want to use the [Chunk](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/new-theme-chunk/) theme from [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com) but:

- I can't find it via the theme admin area of my local wordpress installation
- I can't find a way to download a `.zip` file

Is there a way to do this?  If any further information is required I can provide as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chunk theme is [currently under review](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5249). It has been set as unapproved by the WordPress.org theme review team. If the author makes the corrections it will be available in the [WordPress theme repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/).

Answer (score 3):

The theme may be under review, but it is available via SVN at http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/chunk/1.0/ or via zip at http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/download/chunk.1.0.zip?nostats=1

So you can download it and use it with self-hosted Wordpress.

Comment: I know it can be downloaded, but there's possible issues for users to download a theme with a vulnerability unknowingly. Maybe not this theme, but it's probably best to not suggest downloading themes that aren't approved.

Comment: Thanks - that helps a lot.  Is there any way to know that a theme is unapproved?  I couldn't find an indication of that at http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/chunk/

Comment: I don't think the themes at WordPress.com go through the same process as the themes at WordPress.org. You might find the answer here: http://make.wordpress.org/themes/about/how-to-join-wptrt/ , or maybe Chip Bennett @ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3966/chip-bennett will chime in with an answer.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:
http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5249